# Convert CharSequence to Float

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android, rx-binding

I am trying to convert the item emitted from an observer to another type. I tried the `map` function with no success.

```
mObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(mEditText).map(a -> Float.parseFloat(a.toString()));
```

Using as above I get this compiler error:

```
Error:(37, 70) error: incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: CharSequence
lower bounds: Float
where R,T are type-variables:
R extends Object declared in method <R>map(Func1<? super T,? extends R>)
T extends Object declared in class Observable
```

Is there any operator which can achieve the conversion `CharSequence` to `Float` I need?

Comment: please try String.valueOf(a) hope that helps..

Comment: It doesn't work. The error I pointed out has something to do to returning a Float from the Map operator

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **Cast()** ?

- cast( ) — cast all items from the source Observable into a particular type before reemitting them

Reference
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables